# MFC button click to enable and disable a function

Tags: c++, button, mfc

Ii have issues in using the button click on the MFC environment. I'mrequired to make a button click to execute a certain function and then unclick it to disable the function. Meaning if I click again the function will become false.

```
void CTacNavDlg::OnBnClickedBtnInfo()
{   
   oglFunction.enablePopup = true;
}
```

Is there a way to this on MFC?

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? Toggling a variable value sounds a trivial task to me. I don't understand your issue. Sorry.

Comment: What do you mean by "disable" a function?

Comment: How can on first click the function will be true and second click the function will be false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void CTacNavDlg::OnBnClickedBtnInfo()
{   
    oglFunction.enablePopup = ! oglFunction.enablePopup;
}
```

- First  click => `oglFunction.enablePopup = true`
- Second click => `oglFunction.enablePopup = false`
- Third  click => `oglFunction.enablePopup = true`
- ....

Comment: Thank you, this is what i been looking for, but i am not quite understand the implementation of the =! that cause the first click true, second click false and etc.

Comment: Even if the simplest of forms you just use a if/else ladder.

Comment: @ThingThing it depend from the initial value of `oglFunction.enablePopup` in the `oglFunction` constructor.

Comment: Duplication of state information is the first step in implementing a system that allows for inconsistent state. The UI is perfectly capable of storing the state information for you. There's no need to invent a twin, whose sole purpose is to introduce bugs (well, not it's sole purpose; it also makes the code harder to read, and increases the overall mental tax required to understand it).

Answer (score 3):

This functionality is already built into the OS. You only need to change the button to a checkbox, and add the [BS_PUSHLIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/button-styles) button style. This is easiest done by editing the resource script. Assuming that your dialog resource is defined something like this:

```
IDD_PUSHLIKEBUTTON_DIALOG DIALOGEX ...
...
BEGIN
    PUSHBUTTON      "Up",IDC_PUSHLIKE_BTN_1,7,7,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Up",IDC_PUSHLIKE_BTN_2,79,7,50,14
END
```

you need to change it to read this instead:

```
IDD_PUSHLIKEBUTTON_DIALOG DIALOGEX ...
...
BEGIN
    AUTOCHECKBOX      "Up",IDC_PUSHLIKE_BTN_1,7,7,50,14,BS_PUSHLIKE
    AUTOCHECKBOX      "Up",IDC_PUSHLIKE_BTN_2,79,7,50,14,BS_PUSHLIKE
END
```

The checkbox sends a `WM_COMMAND` message to its parent, whenever it gets clicked. The MFC way to respond to messages is to add an entry into the message map of the parent. For simplicity, I'm going to bind a range to a single handler:

```cpp
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(..., CDialogEx)
    ...
    ON_COMMAND_RANGE(IDC_PUSHLIKE_BTN_1, IDC_PUSHLIKE_BTN_2, &OnPushlikeBtn)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

The following message handler implementation responds by toggling the button text. It shows how to determine the current state as well:

```cpp
void CPushLikeButtonDlg::OnPushlikeBtn(UINT nID)
{
    auto const btn_handle { ::GetDlgItem(m_hWnd, nID) };
    auto const is_checked { Button_GetCheck(btn_handle) == BST_CHECKED };
    ::SetWindowTextW(btn_handle, is_checked ? L"Down" : L"Up");
}
```

This produces output that looks similar to this:

[image: Sample UI]

The result is a checkbox with the appearance of a pushbutton. That used to be more common before the introduction of visual styles. Today, you rarely see this, because it makes for a confusing user experience. The flat user interfaces removes the 3D effect, making it near impossible to visually decide between the pushed and hover state.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61056141/2287576) provided by **IInspectable**.

It is quite easy to use the Resource Editor to create these controls.

- Step 1 — Add a **Check Box** control to your dialog:

[image: Add Check Box]

- Step 2 — Set the **Push Like** property to `True`:

[image: set Push Like property]

- Step 3 — Resize your control:

[image: Resized control on dialog]

You can also set **Radio** controls as **Push Like** too.